# fetch-min-size & max-poll-records sping kafka configurations does not work as expected

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am working on an Spring boot application with spring kafka which listens to a single topic of kafka and then segregates the records for respective categories, creates a json file out of it and uploads it to AWS S3.

I am receiving huge data volumes in Kafka topics and I need to make sure the json files are chunked appropriately huge to limit the number of json uploaded to S3.

Below is my `application.yml` configuration for kafka consumer.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: newton
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      fetch-max-wait: 
        seconds: 1 
      fetch-min-size: 500000000
      max-poll-records: 50000000
      value-deserializer: com.forwarding.application.consumer.model.deserializer.MeasureDeserializer
```

I have created a listener for reading the topic continuously.

Even with the above configuration, I am receiving records in console as follows:

```
   2019-03-27T15:25:56.02+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-03-27 09:55:56.024  INFO 8 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.s.n.f.a.s.impl.ConsumerServiceImpl     : Time taken(ms) 56. No Of measures: 60
   2019-03-27T15:25:56.21+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/2] OUT 2019-03-27 09:55:56.210  INFO 8 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.s.n.f.a.s.impl.ConsumerServiceImpl     : Time taken(ms) 80. No Of measures: 96
   2019-03-27T15:25:56.56+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-03-27 09:55:56.560  INFO 8 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.s.n.f.a.s.impl.ConsumerServiceImpl     : Time taken(ms) 76. No Of measures: 39
   2019-03-27T15:25:56.73+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/2] OUT 2019-03-27 09:55:56.732  INFO 8 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.s.n.f.a.s.impl.ConsumerServiceImpl     : Time taken(ms) 77. No Of measures: 66
```

Can anyone please let me know what can be configured to get the received records as per the configuration in `application.yml`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just copied your configuration (except the max wait - see the syntax I used) and it worked fine...

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: newton
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      fetch-max-wait: 1s
      fetch-min-size: 500000000
      max-poll-records: 50000000
```

```
2019-03-27 13:43:55.454  INFO 98982 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 1000
    fetch.min.bytes = 500000000
    group.id = newton
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 50000000
    ...
```

You set arbitrary properties that are not directly supported as boot properties, using the `...properties` property.

e.g.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        max.poll.interval.ms: 300000
```

or

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
         max:
           poll:
             interval:
               ms: 300000
```

The [documentation is here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props).

> The properties supported by auto configuration are shown in Appendix A, Common application properties. Note that, for the most part, these properties (hyphenated or camelCase) map directly to the Apache Kafka dotted properties. Refer to the Apache Kafka documentation for details.
>
> The first few of these properties apply to all components (producers, consumers, admins, and streams) but can be specified at the component level if you wish to use different values. Apache Kafka designates properties with an importance of HIGH, MEDIUM, or LOW. Spring Boot auto-configuration supports all HIGH importance properties, some selected MEDIUM and LOW properties, and any properties that do not have a default value.
>
> Only a subset of the properties supported by Kafka are available directly through the KafkaProperties class. If you wish to configure the producer or consumer with additional properties that are not directly supported, use the following properties:
>
> `spring.kafka.properties.prop.one=first`
>
> `spring.kafka.admin.properties.prop.two=second`
>
> `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.prop.three=third`
>
> `spring.kafka.producer.properties.prop.four=fourth`
>
> `spring.kafka.streams.properties.prop.five=fifth`

Comment: Thanks for the reference Gary, appreciate it, but the below properties are provided as suggestions by Spring Tool Suite itself for the application.yml

``
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      fetch-max-wait: 
        seconds: 1 
      fetch-min-size: 500000000
      max-poll-records: 50000000
``
I can try to update it under consumer.properties as per your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake; those are indeed first class Boot properties; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). See the edit to my answer - your syntax for the max wait is wrong but otherwise everything works for me.

Comment: Thanks Gary, your solution worked. :)

I was able to improve the performance 8 times.

Comment: @GaryRussell in my case i am using `max-poll-records: 5` on in consumer but it consume single message all time. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/57310585/6097074

Comment: @GaryRussell I edited my question. Help me to solve my question